# UserControl DataContext defined at XAML page level

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-runtime, uwp

I defined a DataContext for a UserControl at XAML page level as follows (the last line being the relevant one):

```
<UserControl
  x:Class="Sample.MyUserControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:data="using:Sample.Models"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="768"
  d:DesignWidth="1024"
  DataContext="data:TestDataCollection">
```

The aim is to be able to access the DataContext object in the page hosting the UserControl as follows, **myUserControl** being the `x:Name` for the UserControl.

```
TestDataCollection tdc = myUserControl.DataContext as TestDataCollection;
```

Everything is working fine with data binding and UI displaying and updating as expected on the UWP platform.

The only one problem is that the above code line is not returning the expected DataContext object. In fact, myUserControl.DataContext during debugging shows a string with a value "data:TestDataCollection" (same as in the above XAML code) rather than an object of type `TestDataCollection`.

Here is another strange thing: If I set the DataContext in codebehind as:

```
this.DataContext = new TestDataCollection();
```

the problem with be gone, i.e., **(myUserControl.DataContext as TestDataCollection)** returns the DataContext object as expected.

What am I doing wrong in setting the page DataContext in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `DataContext="data:TestDataCollection"`, you're doing nothing more than setting a **string** value. If you want a viewmodel **object** to be set, you have to use following syntax:

```
<UserControl
  x:Class="Sample.MyUserControl"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:data="using:Sample.Models"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="768"
  d:DesignWidth="1024">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <data:TestDataCollection />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
</UserControl>
```

Note that your usercontrol will also inherit a `DataContext` from the page it's used on. So in most scenarios it's not necessary to set it explicitly in your control, while you will still be able to access it in code behind (as it's set by the page implicitly).

Comment: > By using DataContext="data:TestDataCollection", you're doing nothing more than setting a string value.
> 

But this makes the data binding to work hence the DataContext must be working, perhaps for setting, but not getting back an object.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get the > markdown to work in above.
A related point: aren't the two XAML code (mine and yours) equivalent? How do you explain the difference?

Comment: Thanks, yes I changed for better clarity.
It works with what you suggested, thanks for this. But leaves me an auxiliary question which is less important to me at present: The question I posed in the above comment: Why are the two XAML code versions different, when they appear to be the same?

Comment: They appear to be the same, but the first version is interpreted as a string value, while the second is interpreted as an object. That's why for design data, you need a markup syntax as well: `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=data:TestDataCollection}"` instead of just using a string

Comment: Well explained, thanks.
Will take note of this but I still don't get the logic behind why DataContext string setting works only to take me some way and fail when I want an object back. I have seen many illogical things so I can live with this rather minor one.